# invalid argument supplied for foreach()!

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

can you help me to fix error.

Here's the line of my code which have an error:

```
$filename = str_replace(' ','-',$HTTP_POST_FILES['thumbimg']['name']);

if ($filename != "") {  

    $valid = 0;
    $temp = explode('.',$filename);
    $filetype = $temp[count($temp)];

    foreach ($imageFileType as $ext) {
        if ($filetype == $ext) {
            $valid = 1;
        }
    }

    if ($valid = 0) {
        $error .= "<li>File is not a valid image.</li>";
    }

    $filesize = str_replace($HTTP_POST_FILES['thumbimg']['size']);

    if ($error == "" ) {
        copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['thumbimg']['tmp_name'], $showPathAdmin.$sID.'/'.$filename);
        $query = "UPDATE `shows` SET `thumbnail` = '$filename' WHERE sID = '$sID' ";
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'.mysql_error());
    }
}   

foreach($_POST['castdelete'] as $deletecast){

    unlink($showPathAdmin.$sID.'/'.$deletecast);

}
```

Comment: In you code your call `str_replace()` is missing the first to arguments?

Comment: can you suggest me any code on my error?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? I guess the above should be changed to `$filesize = str_replace(' ', '-', $HTTP_POST_FILES['thumbimg']['size']);`. Enable error reporting and see what kind of error you really are getting. Then edit your quetsion and include the error message.

Comment: Where have you defined `$imageFileType`?

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to call `str_replace()` on the actual filesize at all?

Comment: thank you guys. i found a solution my error is the $HTTP_POST_FILES i change it to $_FILES